# Simple webpage serve with Arduino ethernet shield on SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, sd-card, web-server

I have been experiment with the arduino uno board from few days but can't seem to make it serve web page stored in SD card of ethernet shield.

If I print the contents of the file to serial it works properly, even embedding the HTML code works fine, but `client.write()` just produces a never ending garbage text of `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ`

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SD.h>
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 115);
EthernetServer server(80);

File webFile;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    server.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);

// initialize SD card
Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
    return;
}

Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
// check for index.htm file
if (!SD.exists("index.htm")) {
    Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
    return;  // can't find index file
}
Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm file.");
}

void loop()
{
EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

if (client) {  // got client?
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
        if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
            char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
            // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
            // respond to client only after last line received
            if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                // send a standard http response header
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                client.println("Connection: close");
                Serial.println("starting to open htm");
                client.println();
                // send web page
                webFile = SD.open("index.htm");        // open web page file
                if (webFile) {
                    while(webFile.available()) {
                        client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
                    }
                    webFile.close();
                }
                break;
            }
            // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
            if (c == '\n') {
                // last character on line of received text
                // starting new line with next character read
                currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } 
            else if (c != '\r') {
                // a text character was received from client
                currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }
        } // end if (client.available())
    } // end while (client.connected())
    delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
    client.stop(); // close the connection
} // end if (client)
}
```

Sorry for the poor formatting, I just copied it from tutorial, please help me out.

Comment: Where are you viewing the results of `client.write()`? From a web browser? Have you tried opening the file before you start writing to the client, maybe in `setup()`? In case opening the file takes too long and is causing the process to time out? Show us the contents of "index.htm".

Answer (score 1):

"ÿ" is character code 255, the erased state of a Flash/EPROM/SD. Check if your SD card format OK, 'index.htm' file is there, and your code can read it.

Comment: SD card is formated in FAT16, and I've been able to get the data of files on serial output | replacing client.write() to Serial.write() ; i.e. it seems file is accessible

Answer (score 1):

Me I solve the problem by using : "/index~1.htm" 
I see that the file name is seen like that using the cardinfo.ino from Example

Comment: because you copied a file with 4 characters length "html" extension to file system with max 3 chars extension